# Checkout-shipping - add placeholder to email input field

Tags: magento2.4

I'm trying to add placeholder to email input box.
For that I prepared layout overwrite in my custom theme in *Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml*

```
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">

                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">

                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">

                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">

                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">

                                            <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">

                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">

                                                    <item name="customer-email" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Please enter your valid email address</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
```

Email is controlled by Amazon_Payment module, so I created in my theme
*web/template/form/element/email.html*

```
<form class="form form-login" data-role="email-with-possible-login"
      data-bind="submit:login"
      method="post">
    <fieldset id="customer-email-fieldset" class="fieldset" data-bind="blockLoader: isLoading">
        <div class="field required">
            <label class="label" for="customer-email">
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'Email Address ohoho'"></span>
            </label>
            <div class="control _with-tooltip">
                <input class="input-text"
                       type="email"
                       data-bind="
                            placeholder: placeholder,
                            textInput: email,
                            hasFocus: emailFocused"
                       name="username"
                       
                       data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"
                       id="customer-email" />
                <!-- ko template: 'ui/form/element/helper/tooltip' --><!-- /ko -->
                <span class="note" data-bind="fadeVisible: isPasswordVisible() == false"><!-- ko i18n: 'You can create an account after checkout.'--><!-- /ko --></span>
            </div>
        </div>  .........
```

Crucial line is in data-bind where I'v put placeholder and value for it.
In chrome dev tools I can see placeholder value (with knockout extension)
but that value is not set in input.
https://prnt.sc/v4ia2p

How do I add custom text to email placeholder on checkout page (shipping)?

PS. label is edited correctly..added "ohohoh" to it and it shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no custom binding for placeholder, you will have to use a different notation:

```
attr: {placeholder: placeholder}
```

Like this:

```
 <input class="input-text"
                       type="email"
                       data-bind="
                            textInput: email,
                            hasFocus: emailFocused,
                            attr: {placeholder: placeholder}"
                       name="username"
                       data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"
                       id="customer-email" />
```

Comment: thank you, works fine now